# Is MessageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly() required put permissions for queue

Tags: java, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean, message-listener

When we use `MessageDrivenContext.setRollbackOnly()`, `Container` will rollback the transaction contest so the message will be put back to `JMS` queue.

Is it required explicit put permission for that queue or as its transaction level so container will handle it without explicit put permission.

I am using **IBM MQ**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IBM MQ when the GET operation happens under SYNCPOINT and is later backed out instead of committed it is a cancellation of the GET operation and would not require explicit PUT permission to the queue.